# boost MPL - doing transform on joint_view

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

Consider:

```
template<typename T>
struct MakeVectorOfType
{
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
};

typedef boost::mpl::vector<int, double> TScalarTypes;
typedef boost::mpl::transform<TScalarTypes, MakeVectorOfType<boost::mpl::placeholders::_1>>::type TVectorTypes;
typedef boost::mpl::joint_view<TScalarTypes, TVectorTypes>::type TTypes;

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    T value;
};

template<typename T>
struct MakeWrapper
{
    typedef Wrapper<T> type;
};

typedef boost::mpl::transform<
    TScalarTypes::type,
    MakeWrapper<boost::mpl::placeholders::_1>
>::type TScalarWrapperTypes; // <-- Works

typedef boost::mpl::transform<
    TTypes::type,
    MakeWrapper<boost::mpl::placeholders::_1>
>::type TAllWrapperTypes; // <-- Compiler error
```

So essentially I have some types in an MPL sequence, I make another sequence with std::vectors of those types, then I want to do something with the union of the two. If I want to do another transform on that union (using joint_view), I get the following compiler error (using MSVC2017):

```
1>e:\source\trunk\thirdparty\boost\mpl\clear.hpp(31): error C2504: 'boost::mpl::clear_impl<boost::mpl::aux::joint_view_tag>::apply<Sequence>': base class undefined
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Sequence=boost::mpl::joint_view<TScalarTypes,TVectorTypes>
1>        ]
```

(... plus a lot more tracing back to the code above, obviously)

The other one (where I do the transform directly on the sequence) works fine, so AFAICT it's the combination of applying a transform on a joint_view that is the problem here. So is it because the joint_view isn't a 'real' sequence but merely a 'view'? I can make a copy of the joint_view first and then apply the transform on that copy, but it just bugs me that I can't get this to work in one go.

Answer (score 0):

It seems mtl::transform is unable to handle the sequence generated by joint_view. joint_view generates a 'A lazy Forward Sequence' which mtl::transform may not support.

You can use boost::mpl::copy as below to solve the problem,

```
typedef typename boost::mpl::copy<TVectorTypes, boost::mpl::back_inserter<TScalarTypes> >::type TTypes;
```